# Trying to repair a leaking faucet handle, but can't determine the brand

Tags: plumbing

The hot/left handle leaks when you turn on hot OR cold.  I have pictures/video attached to show where the leak is coming from.  Hoping someone can identify the brand, so I can tell what part to replace?  Thanks in advance.[image: working cold side][image: whole thing][leak in action](https://plus.google.com/photos/112114389439324674128/albums/6126839656947609073?banner=pwa)

Answer (score 1):

That looks a moderately standard tap

What I'd do,

- Shut off water to the faucet (isolation valve below or elsewhere).
- Use pliers to pull the spring-clip off.
- Use the correct sized spanner to undo the nut.
- Remove the assembly.
- Take the parts to a plumbers-merchants or DIY store.
- Show an assistant the parts and ask for advice about replacement washer.
- Buy an appropriate replacement washer.
- Swap old for new washer.
- Replace parts in faucet.
- Carefully open isolation valve.

Comment: +1 for suggesting taking the part to the store. Even if you cant find a replacement part from one brand (the original maker), a similar part from another manufacturer will often do the trick. A good store assistant will have an idea what parts may be exchangeable.